# Dump data in json format from two tables from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following scenario.
I have 2 tables as follow
Table 1
ID, Name, Desc, Seo

Table 2
ID, Table1_ID, Relation_Table1_ID

in Table 1 I have all my data that I need as:

```
-----------------------------------
|ID | Name        |Desc      |Seo |
-----------------------------------
| 1 | Smith       |Father    |f   |
| 2 | Jonh        |Son       |j   |
| 3 | Margat      |Mother    |m   |
| 4 | Bis3        |son       |b1  |
| 5 | Bis2        |son       |b2  |
| 6 | Bis1        |son       |b3  |
| 7 | Lanos       |Brother   |l   |
-----------------------------------
```

And then we have our table 2 as follow

```
-------------------------------------
|ID | Table1_ID   |Relation_Table1_id|
--------------------------------------
| 1 |     1       |         4        |
| 2 |     1       |         5        |
| 3 |     3       |         6        |
| 4 |     3       |         2        |
| 5 |     7       |         0        |
--------------------------------------
```

So far I have my first table dump with jSON() as follow:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$dump1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 ") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $getList = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dump1)) { 
    $getList[] = $row;
}
  print json_encode($getList);   exit;
?>
```

That code will give me the following:

```
[
  {
    "ID":"1",
    "Name":"Smith",
    "Desc":"Father",
    "Seo":"f"
  },
{
    "ID":"2",
    "Name":"Jonh",
    "Desc":"Son",
    "Seo":"j"
  },
{
    "ID":"3",
    "Name":"Margat",
    "Desc":"Mother",
    "Seo":"m"
  }... ... ...
]
```

What I can't figure is how do I get the following

```
[
  {
    "ID":"1",
    "Name":"Smith",
    "Desc":"Father",
    "Seo":"f",
        "Relations":[
            {
             "ID":"4",
             "Name":"Bis3",
             "Desc":"Son",
             "Seo":"b1"
            }
          ]
  },
  {
    "ID":"3",
    "Name":"Margat",
    "Desc":"Father",
    "Seo":"f",
        "Relations":[
            {
             "ID":"6",
             "Name":"Bis2",
             "Desc":"Son",
             "Seo":"b2"
            },

            {
             "ID":"2",
             "Name":"Jonh",
             "Desc":"Son",
             "Seo":"j"
            }
          ]
  }... ... ...

]
```

In plain text it would be something like

```
  ID 1 Smith
  |   |_ID 4 Bis3
  |   
  |_ ID 3 Margat
      |_ID 5 Bis2
      |_ID 2 Jonh
```

I'm learning how to use json and I just got the first part as you can see, but my lack of knowledge of SQL and php wont let me get the what I really want, so please can any one help me achieve this scenario please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through $getlist

then query

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($getlist); $i++){
    "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table1_ID = $getlist[$i]['ID']"
// get the result however way
$getlist[$i]['something'] = $result;
}
```

then take the result of that, inside the loop, and assign it to whichever key of getlist you want
for example

hopefully thats specific enough. let me know if you have problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join across the two tables. First, join the second table with the first table. This can be done with the following code:

```
select * from table_2 as t2 join table_1 as t1 on t1.id = t2.rel_id;
```

which results in:

```
+------+-----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
| ID   | table1_id | rel_id | ID   | name | desc | seo  |
+------+-----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
|    4 |         3 |      2 |    2 | John | Son  | j    |
|    1 |         1 |      4 |    4 | Bis3 | son  | b1   |
|    2 |         1 |      5 |    5 | Bis2 | son  | b2   |
|    3 |         3 |      6 |    6 | Bis1 | son  | b3   |
+------+-----------+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

now we want to join the columns if the table1_id is the same. This can be done with the `GROUP_CONCAT` command:

```
select table1_id,group_concat(t1.name) as name_rel,
group_concat(t1.desc) as desc_rel, group_concat(seo) as seo_rel,
group_concat(rel_id) as id_rel from table_2 as t2 join table_1 as t1 on 
t2.rel_id = t1.id group by t2.table1_id
```

which results in:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
| table1_id | name_rel  | desc_rel | seo_rel | id_rel |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
|         1 | Bis2,Bis3 | son,son  | b2,b1   | 5,4    |
|         3 | John,Bis1 | Son,son  | j,b3    | 2,6    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
```

The `as` command can be used to rename columns in the output. Try running the query without it and you should see column names like `group_concat(t1.name)` instead of `name_rel`.

Now we want to join this selection with table_1 where the table1_id is the same as the id in table1. This can be done with the following query:

```
select * from (
select table1_id,group_concat(t1.name) as name_rel,
group_concat(t1.desc) as desc_rel, group_concat(seo) as seo_rel,
group_concat(rel_id) as id_rel from table_2 as t2 join table_1 as t1 on
t2.rel_id = t1.id group by t2.table1_id
) as joined_table 
join table_1 as t3 on t3.id = joined_table.table1_id;
```

which results in:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+------+--------+--------+------+
| table1_id | name_rel  | desc_rel | seo_rel | id_rel | ID   | name   | desc   | seo  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+------+--------+--------+------+
|         1 | Bis2,Bis3 | son,son  | b2,b1   | 5,4    |    1 | Smith  | Father | f    |
|         3 | John,Bis1 | Son,son  | j,b3    | 2,6    |    3 | Margat | Mother | m    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+------+--------+--------+------+
```

As you can see, you know have all the data. All that is left is to turn the *_rel columns into separate objects, which can be done in php. <strike>Go ahead and give that a shot. I've gotta go for now, but I'll edit this post later if you're still having trouble.</strike>

Alright, I'm back. My php is rusty, but something along these lines should work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dump1)) { 
    $name_rel = explode("," , $row["name_rel"]);
    $desc_rel = explode("," , $row["desc_rel"]);
    $seo_rel = explode("," , $row["seo_rel"]);
    $id_rel = explode("," , $row["id_rel"]);
    $relations = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($id_rel); ++$i){
        $temp = array("ID" => $id_rel[$i],
                      "Name" => $name_rel[$i],
                      "Desc" => $desc_rel[$i],
                      "Seo" => $seo_rel[$i],);
        $relations[] = $temp ;
    }
    unset($row["id_rel"]);
    unset($row["name_rel"]);
    unset($row["desc_rel"]);
    unset($row["seo_rel"]);
    $row["Relations"] = $relations ;
    $getList[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($getList);   exit;
```

This will create each of the `Relations` objects and add them to the row. The unset commands should remove the keys we no longer care about (id_rel, name_rel, desc_rel, and seo_rel). We no longer care about them because their data should have been moved to the `Relations` object.